# I would like to implement the remarketing tag into my website

Tags: tags

I was wondering if anybody can help me with the implementation of the remarketing tag into my site. I have the codes and I just don't know where to enter them.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're asking about [AdWords](https://support.google.com/adwords/answer/3103357?hl=en)?

Forgive me if I need to ask this but who developed your website? It sounds like you need to have your developer add that bit to the website's code. (If you're actually a developer and I'm talking under your knowledge, go ahead and modify your question!)

Otherwise, if have access to ftp or some other form of modifying files on your server, you can add it yourself. (Before you modify any file, make a duplicate copy in case you have to go back.)

The exact place is going to depend on your templates, located in the `craft/templates/` and likely in the `_layout.html` (or some other file like `header.html` or `footer.html`).

If you're running Google Analytics (which is a safe bet, since you're using AdWords), the easiest way to do it would be to [add a line to your GA tracking code](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/2444872#trackingcode) which probably is already installed.  Just look for `ga('send', 'pageview');` and add `ga('require', 'displayfeatures');` right above that, as in the example given on the page (assuming you're using their newer Universal code).